# Get current date and time in seconds

Tags: c, linux, datetime

```
    time_t rawtime;
struct tm *mytm;
time_t result;

time(&rawtime);

mytm=localtime(&rawtime);
mytm->tm_mon=month-1;
mytm->tm_mday=day;
mytm->tm_year=year-1900;

mytm->tm_sec=0;
mytm->tm_min=0;
mytm->tm_hour=0;

result = mktime(mytm);
```

Above code snippet,I'm expecting result to display the no.of seconds lapsed since 1970,jan-1st for the given date. DD/MM/YYYY stored in day ,month,year
But i'm getting compile error

`error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`

Comment: Sorry,the question is not clear, If user gives day,month,year say
22/01/2010  or 01/02/1990 or any date
I want to get the result in seconds 
In the code,day,month and year contains user given input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
#include <time.h>
```

in your file to fix the error about incomplete type.

*Edit*: Given a day, month, year to find the time in seconds since Jan 1 1970 to midnight on that day:

```
struct tm mytm = { 0 };
time_t result;
mytm.tm_year = year - 1900;
mytm.tm_mon = month - 1;
mytm.tm_mday = day;
result = mktime(&mytm);
if (result == (time_t) -1) {
    /* handle error */
} else {
    printf("%lld\n", (long long) result);
}
```

Note the in ISO C, `mktime()` returns an integral value of type `time_t` that represents the time in the `struct tm *` argument, but the meaning of such an integral value is not necessarily "seconds since Jan 1, 1970".  It need not be in seconds at all.  POSIX mandates that `time()`, `mktime()`, etc., return seconds since Jan 1, 1970, so you should be OK.  I mention the above for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

The "time" function returns the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC.  You do not need to call any other functions.  The time_t type is just an integer type, it's probably equivalent to int.

Comment: It's actually usually `long` - so if you want to print it in a way that will work either way, cast it to `long long`: `printf("%lld", (long long)some_time_t)`

Answer (score 1):

Dietrich is correct, however if you wished to add the number of seconds since the Epoch in a formatted string with other date info, you should consider using `strftime()`.